# Can I quick detonate C4 while another weapon is equipped?

Tags: battlefield-3

When I've placed C4 and have my primary (or other) weapon equipped, is there a way to detonate the C4 without re-equipping the C4 again?

In a previous Battlefield, or maybe it was CoD, you could double-tap reload to do this.

Comment: I definitely remember that in CoD MW2 you could double tap reload on any weapon and detonate the C4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, C4 can only be detonated by the thrower using the fire button or by yours or enemy bullets. C4 could be detonated on MW2 by double-tapping reload, but no such shortcut exists in Battlefield, likely because of their desire to make the game 'realistic'.

Answer (score 2):

Also keep in mind that explosive weapons detonate C4. It is possible (and very handy) to use a shotgun with explosive rounds when you're C4ing things, as this allows you to fire at your C4 to detonate it.

Comment: Pistols can too, but they require more precision